# invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/mobiles reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, next.js

Next.js ===>

> Server Error FetchError: invalid json response body at
> http://localhost:3000/api/mobiles/1 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON
> at position 0 This error happened while generating the page. Any
> console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.***

pages/api/mobiles.js

```
const mobile = [
  {
    id: 1,
    stores: 4,
    name: "realme u1 (3gb Ram , 64Gb Storage)",
    image:
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81sWGJAQX9S._SX569_.jpg",
    price: "9999",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    stores: 4,
    name: "realme u2 (3gb Ram , 64Gb Storage)",
    image:
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81sWGJAQX9S._SX569_.jpg",
    price: "9999",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    stores: 4,
    name: "realme u3 (3gb Ram , 64Gb Storage)",
    image:
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81sWGJAQX9S._SX569_.jpg",
    price: "9999",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    stores: 4,
    name: "realme u4 (3gb Ram , 64Gb Storage)",
    image:
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81sWGJAQX9S._SX569_.jpg",
    price: "9999",
  },
];

// I also tried, but it didn't Work => 

// const allMobs = JSON.Stringyfy(mobile)

// export default (req, res) => {
//   res.status(200).json(allMobs);
// }; 

export default (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json(mobile);
    };
```

Next.js ==>

> Server Error FetchError: invalid json response body at
> http://localhost:3000/api/mobiles/1 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON
> at position 0 This error happened while generating the page. Any
> console logs will be displayed in the terminal window

pages/[mobileID].js

```
export default function MobileID({ mobile }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {mobile.name} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/mobiles`);
  const data = await res.json();
  
  const paths = data.map((mobile) => {
    return {
      params: {
        mobileID: mobile.id.toString()
      },
    };
  });
  
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.mobileID;
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/mobiles/${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { mobile: data },
  };
};
```

Comment: Looks like you server returns an HTML (error) page, not a json. Log the repsonse to see what you get, or call this page in a brower.

Comment: Also you should check the return code before parsing the result

Comment: Did you define a handler in pages/api/mobiles/[id].js